# HYPERLINK to a specific cell

Tags: excel, macos, hyperlink

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets:

1. Product
2. Part Numbers

In `Product` I have a cell with a part number e.g. `021-78965`. This part number is also in `Part Numbers`. I've seen how you can hyperlink to a specific sheet, or tab, in Excel but I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following with the =HYPERLINK() formula:

- Hyperlink to specific sheet, e.g. Part Numbers
- In the specific sheet, search for the text of the hyperlink (i.e. 021-78965), and direct user to that cell.

Comment: You can use `=HYPERLINK("[WorkbookName]'Part Numbers'!" & ADDRESS(1,1),"021-78965")` to create hyperlink to `A1`. Use `MATCH` to adjust address of part in second sheet.